# Amount of Chocolate-chips in a Chocolate-chip cookie?

Tags: chocolate, cookies

I've been making chocalote chip cookies for a while and I just can't decide how many chocolate chips to put in each cookie. So maybe once and for all I can get a good answer to the question:

What is the best percentage of chocolate-chips for a chocolate cookies? And what are the pros and cons for putting more or less chocolate chips?

Comment: I've always just mixed all the chips in with the batter and left it up to chance on how many a single cookie averages.

Comment: Ya, but how much chocolate chips per batter?

Comment: Surely this is a bit subjective... as long as you don't put in so many that the cookies can't hold together, it'll be fine. Besides, if you can't decide how many to put in, maybe that just means there's a range of equally good options for you!

Comment: I'm looking for a slightly more profound answer

Comment: I don't know if a profound answer exists for chocolate chip cookies. And there is also the factor of who your target audience is and what type of chocolate you are using (for sweeter blends, you may not need as many chips).

Comment: As long as you can taste the cookie next to the chocolate, keep adding chocolate :) Seriously, it's all down to personal taste. A very high chocolate concentration can make the cookies taste bitter, or make them fall apart. That'd be too much, obviously.

Comment: lol I put the whole bag in for a gooey chocolatey center!

Comment: A much more interesting question is now how many chips, but how much butter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it depends on your taste and recipe, I can tell you what's my favorite amount.

I tend to chop chocolate to pretty big pieces (cubes approximately 2cm long). I tend to put as many chocolate chips as it takes so that some of them fall off when mixed with the dough. I then additionally push leftover chips in dough when forming cookies. I try to avoid chips that are too small and chocolate powder; somehow the cookies are better when chocolate powder is not mixed into dough. I suppose the contrast between the dough and chocolate chips is what makes them tasty.

Answer (score 6):

Exactly 42 chocolate chips per 3/4 cup of batter.

Comment: Ha. Ha. Very funny, but not very helpful.

Comment: which cup? The green one or the purple one :)

Answer (score 6):

The best percentage depends entirely on your own taste, and the texture and sweetness of your cookie dough. It also depends on the size of the chips. Standard North American chips? Chunks you hacked out of a block of couverture? There are too many variables here to give a good answer.

The only way to find out the 'best' percentage is to experiment and see what you like. Alternatively, find your favourite brand of chocolate chip cookie, and count how many chips are in, say, 10 cookies. Average that number and there you are.

Comment: And, if you've experimented and can't decide what you like, then accept that, pick something somewhere in the middle of the range, and just enjoy your cookies!

Comment: Agreed.  I have to different cookie recipes, one is best with so many chocolate chips there is just barely enough dough to hold them together.  One is best with a light mix scattered through.  "chocolate chip cookies" is a very broad, and subjective category.

Answer (score 3):

My mom and I love to bake chocolate chip cookies together and this is an issue we run into every time- how many chips are too many?

I like to pour in about half of a standard bag of Nestle morsels and spoon out my cookies, while my mom waits until I'm done, then adds the other half a bag of morsels to the other half of the dough, then adds pecans or walnuts and spoons out her batch.

Its all about personal preference and the likes and dislikes of your audience :)

Answer (score 3):

**12.27**

The [original Tollhouse Chocolate Chip Cookie recipe](http://www.cookie-smart.com/tollhouse-chocolate-chip-cookie-recipe.html) calls for two cups of chips or one 12-oz. bag of standard-size semi-sweet chocolate morsels. The recipe makes 60 (rounded tablespoon-sized) cookies. I have a 12 oz. bag of chocolate chips here that indicates in the "Nutrition Facts" box that one serving is equal to 32 chips. It says the bag contains 23 servings. That's 736 chocolate chips per bag. 736 divided by 60 equals an average of 12.27 chocolate chips per cookie.